# rails - Build queries, the combining them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Based on my app, I need to grab users based on a set of conditions.

```
@usersSet1 = XXX based on a bunch of conditions

@usersSet2 = XXX based on a bunch of different conditions

@usersSet3 = XXX based on a bunch of even more different conditions
```

I then want to combine the 3, and take the top 100 records. Any thoughts on getting this done with Rails? thanks

Comment: How do you want to combine them? Appending, ordering, what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define scopes in your model:

```
# model
scope :set1, where(some_conditions), ...
scope :set2, where(some_conditions), ...
scope :set3, where(some_conditions), ...
scope :top_100, limit(100)
```

Give those scopes appropriate names. And of course you need to `order` it by something.
Then you can call:

```
@usersSet1 = User.set1
@usersSet2 = User.set2
@usersSet3 = User.set3

@usersset123 = User.set1.set2.set3.top_100
```

It will `AND` all conditions in set1, set2, and set3.

Comment: Ok turns out this doesn't work because each scope is added to the SQL like so,, SET 1 = XXX, AND set 2 = x, AND set 3, where what I need is OR not AND. ideas?

Comment: There is no simple way of chaining scopes and `OR` them. You have to write new scope that uses `OR` and call it. It is not DRY, but it works. You also can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684311/rails-how-to-chain-scope-queries-with-or-instead-of-and and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016983/chaining-named-scopes-not-working-as-intended

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to do one SQL query pulling back the fields that have those conditions.  For example:

```
@users = User.all(select => "city,state,last_name,first_name,…", :limit => 100)
```

Now you have all of the columns. So you move on to:

```
@usersSet1 = @users.select{|a| a.state == 'Charlotte' && a.state == 'NC') #pulls back users in Charlotte
@usersSet2 = @users.select{|b| b.last_name == 'Smith' } #pulls back users that have the last name of Smith.
@usersSet3 = @users.select{|b| b.first_name == ('John' || 'Joe') } #pulls back users that have the first name of John or Joe.
```

And so on…  This, in my opinion, is much more scalable.

Comment: Thanks but the issue here is that each query needs another table for the logic. like permissions, etc