# Rails 4: how to use named scope with has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app Project (model) `has_many` Videos (model). I have a named scope in the videos model:

```
scope :live, where( is_deleted: 0, sent_to_api: 1 )
```

In one of my project views, I do this (project is an instance of Project):

```
project.videos.live.size
```

What I expect to get is the number of projects in *that specific project* but instead I get the number of videos in *any* project. It's as if `.live` is not returning a subset from `.videos` but rather replacing it.

I see it explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016983/chaining-named-scopes-not-working-as-intended) that chaining named scopes with one another should be combined with logical AND but when applied to an "association method" [<--not sure the proper terminology for `.videos` in this context] that doesn't seem to be happening.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: First check what Video.live.size is returning

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh It's returning the total number of "live" videos.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe it should read like this in Rails 4:

```
scope :live, -> { where(is_deleted: 0, sent_to_api: 1) }
```

The rails 4 docs and all examples in it show you passing in a callable object to the scope to ensure it gets called each time. If it doesn't work like this try implementing it as a class method and see how that works out for you.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I'm new to Ruby/Rails and I haven't seen that `->` syntax before. Is it standard Ruby or something added by Rails?

Comment: My (limited) understanding is that it's new with Rails 4. I remember scopes from my Rails 3 projects that certainly didn't require to pass in the object like that. My assumption is also supported by the Rails 3 guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#scopes which don't show objects being passed to any of the scopes, so that about assures it for me.

Comment: You're definitely right that it's a Rails 4 thing because I see a deprication warning in the log when I write a scope without it. But my follow-up question was actually just about the `->` operator its self. I've not seen it before and I just want to understand what it is.

Comment: @Emerson - The `->` is syntax for a "Stabby Lambda". Shorthand for a traditional lambda block.

Comment: @veritas1 Thanks!! I suspected it was something like that.

Comment: @Emerson Side note on this, default_scope can just be passed a block, no proc object required (although it will work that way as well).

Comment: @MikeWaldrup Just default_scope or any named scope? I'm more comfortable with blocks, so that's good to know.

Comment: @Emerson  Docs show just default_scope with that option. Not exactly sure why though.

Answer (score 3):

I would just go for class methods and leave scopes behind. The syntax is much simpler because it's just like any other class method, including passing parameters to it.

Try:

```
def self.live
  where( is_deleted: 0, sent_to_api: 1 )
end
```

And then:

```
project.videos.live.size
```

and see if it helps.

For more info, read [here](http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/).

Comment: Just to note.. scopes and class methods behave differently

Comment: the linked article is out of date. the author edited it saying that the bug mentioned was fixed, and he uses scopes for simple things.  From the rails docs 4.1 "This (scope) is exactly the same as defining a class method, and which you use is a matter of personal preference"